# How do I map the Run Configuration from IntelliJ to VSCode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, run-configuration

I want to have the same run configuration I have on `Intellij` the same as I do for `VS Code`. But I am not sure how to go about doing that. I tried the `launch.json` on VSCode but I am not sure what fields I have to put to make it work.

Anyone with experience with this?

**Here is what I am referencing:**
[image]

Essentially when I click the Run Button on the top right of the intellij it runs that particular run configuration picture.

Is there a way for me to do the same on VSCode?

Comment: I'm sorry it's a little hard to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. Can you describe your problem in detail and clearly?

Comment: Essentially when I click the "Run" button on the top right. It runs those settings in IntelliJ. I want to be able to do the same thing in VSCode. That particular configuration (the picture you see) runs all the Junit tests with those specific settings. How can I do the same thing in VSCode?

Comment: [`task.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) might help you.

Comment: I know but I dont know how to map it properly. If I know the cmd line commands for Intellij I might be able to map it.

Answer (score 1):

1. If .vscode/launch.json doesn't exist in your workspace, you could click the link "**create a launch.json file**" and Java Debugger will create a initial launch.json file with some base configuration for your Java application.

   [image]
2. Type a `""` in launch.json, VS Code will provide a list of completion suggestions on the supported configs. If you want to add environment variables for your program, you can type `"env": { "key": "value"}`.

   [image]

Comment: I understand that, but I dont know what fields are compatible/I should put. The screenshot is those fields, but when I put "gradle" as key and value "dee_api_gw", it does nothing. So im not sure what to put

Comment: If you're talking about how to add environment variables, the `env` is exactly for that. Could you pls share your launch.json configuration?

Answer (score -1):

There is this project which lets you convert Jetbrains run configurations to VSCode

[jetbrains-vscode](https://github.com/topscoder/jetbrains-vscode)

Comment: This didn't work for me. The output configuration is empty:
{
  "configurations": []
}

Comment: This seems to only work for Python run configs.  Line [55 in convert.py](https://github.com/topscoder/jetbrains-vscode/blob/7ca4a8009fcbc08af063628bdd5c4a72eaea4eec/convert.py#L55) specifies to continue `if node.getAttribute('type') != 'PythonConfigurationType'`...